# How would I represent and model this relation?

Tags: django, database-design

So I have the following logic. A user creates a trade, this trade contains items a user wants and items a user has. These has and wants are represented as two separate many to many relationships.

However, here is where I am getting a little confused. These items can come from different models. For example I have a model set up for particular items, say business items which have unique characteristics and a second model for engineer items. Now these items can both be traded within the same trade.

Furthermore if I were to add more models representing other unique trade items how would I be able to add this to the many to many relationship without overhaul of the structure or data.

For illustration:

```
class ItemTrade(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
    have_items = models.ManyToManyField()
    want_items = models.ManyToManyField()
    num_watch = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    num_views = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)

class Model1(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey('DotaItemType',null=True,blank=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    index= models.IntegerField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey('DotaItemType',null=True,blank=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The indexes will overlap for each item which means that I would also need to have secondary field to identify which model the item belongs to. What is the best possible method to represent this relation?

The only way I can think of is to have a unique many to many field for each model relation within the trade but I am not sure if this is the simplest and most effective way of accomplishing this.

Comment: You should take a look at Generic Foreign Keys. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations It might be a bit of work to get it to work as a ManyToMany, but it's what you're trying to do now. Another option would be to use Multi-Table inheritance. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks, I am currently having a look and it seems pretty complicated in terms of implementing a many to many relationship. Another way I was thinking of doing this was to store the model and index as a sort of identification pair within the pivot table that is created. Do you think this would be simpler and work well with high traffic? In terms of this solution is it possible to specify what the pivot table looks like i.e I want to add a column that identifies the model it relates to?